# evaluate HTML content from item in region Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In the database table I have a CLOB column that stores content with html markup. To display the content, I have a "Hidden" item called P4_DESCRIPTION and in the region that I want to display the value of the item, I use `&P4_DESCRIPTION.` .

Unfortunatelly it is not evaluating the HTML markup and displays the content as it is stored in the DB.
I also tried to change the P4_DESCRIPTION from "Hidden" to "Display Only" but I have the same problem. A workaround that I found is that if I have the P4_DESCRIPTION as "Display Only" and in the region I keep the `&P4_DESCRIPTION.` then the `&P4_DESCRIPTION.` will evaluate the HTML code. In this case I have hide with CSS the item and I will have the result I want. But I suppose it's a dirty way of doing it.

What is the clean way of displaying the content of the column that contains HTML markup? (btw to create the content of that column I used the **rich text editor** field)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the item to Display Only and set **Escape special characters** on it to No.

Comment: Just spent over 2 hours trying to figure this out. Thanks!